# スマートニュースやGunosyのようなUIの実装

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

お世話になります。

はじめてmonacaを使って、スマートニュースやGunosyの様な左右のスワイプでタブが切り替わるようなアプリの作成を予定しております。

一通り、monacaやONSEN UIのマニュアル等に目を通したのですが、スワイプでタブを切り替えるような機能が見当たりませんでした。

もし出来るならコードをお教えいただけないでしょうか？もしくはそのようなコードが公開されているのでしたらご教授願います。（検索しましたが見当たりませんでした…。）

以上、恐縮ではございますがよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

`<ons-gesture-detector>`を使うと、スワイプなどのジェスチャーを受け取ることができます。

http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#DetectingFingerGestures

ジェスチャーを受け取ったら、`<ons-tabbar>`の`setActiveTab()`メソッドを呼び出すことで、タブが切り替えられると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます。